# tkinter Window is freezing on simple script (no threading or else)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have written a simple script to get started with GUI programming in python using tkinter. When I execute the following script, the window freezes immediately. After a while Windows tells me, that Python "is not responding".

Since I'm new to Python/tkinter and the provided script is pretty basic, I have no idea how to solve the problem.

The following script is saved in the folder "test" and is called "test.py"

```py
import tkinter

def leave():
    window.destroy()

window = tkinter.Tk()

b = tkinter.Button(window, text="Exit", command = leave)
b.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

and to execute I run:

> > [...]\test> python .\test.py

There is no error or anything else showing up in the console (PowerShell). The only thing I get is the Windows message "python is not responding". Also when I hover over the window, the mouse icon is changing to the loading icon.

//edit

OS: Windows 10 Pro

Python: 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

Answer (score 0):

After I tried to find the tinker version, I stumbled over the command:

```
python -m tinker
```

see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html

After executed this command, my problem was solved.